# Is $2\int\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}*\frac{dx}{dt}dt=(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 $ true??

Tags: integration, derivatives, soft-question

I was watching a video online about motion under inverse square law [here](https://unacademy.com/lesson/motion-under-inverse-square-law/GWCG0KPD) and the producer mentioned that,
$$2\int\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}*\frac{dx}{dt}dt=\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 $$
i donot understand why is that so. I searched online but i didn't find anything! Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Take the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 2):

It's an application of substitution. We have that:
$$
\int u \; \frac{du}{dt} \; dt = \int u \; du
$$
Now replace $u$ by $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Answer (score 2):

With $$u=\frac {dx}{dt}$$ we get $$\frac {du}{dt}=\frac {d^2x}{dt ^2}$$

The integral becomes $$\int udu=\frac {1}{2}u^2$$